# Standard output/input/error file in c

Tags: c, stdout, stdin, stderr

Is the standard input file- `stdin` is **always** the keyboard, the standard output file- `stdout` is **always** the screen, and the standard error file- `stderr` is **always** the screen?
and why?

Comment: No, not **always**, as they can be redirected (inside the program itself and outside it). But **by default**, yes, they are.

Comment: how can I redirected them?

Answer (score 3):

By default, yes. 
But the reason that system is so flexible and powerful is that it can be redirected (by the user or the program both)

When you type in a shell

```
command > file
```

You actually redirect the stdout of `command` into the file `file`.

By doing

```
command1 | command2
```

you redirect the stdout of `command1` to the stdin of `command2`

Programatically, the [file descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) 0 is always stdin, 1 stdout, 2 stderr.

I suggest learning about [`dup` and `dup2`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) for redirecting them programatically.

Example

```
int file = open("out.txt", O_APPEND | O_WRONLY);
int stdout_cpy = dup(1);    // Clone stdout to a new descriptor
dup2(file, 1);              // Make file the new fd 1, i.e. redirect stdout to out.txt
```

Comment: Programatically 0, 1 and 2 are not always `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. If you close one of them (`stdout` for example), and create a new file descriptor (by example with a call to `socket`) it will take the first file descriptor available (in this example `stdout`).

Comment: Yes, but this new fd will act as stdout. By that I mean calling `printf` for instance will write to that fd. So by any mean, this will become stdout.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just misunderstood what you mean by "always".